# Не срабатывает select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Ребята очень нужна ваша помощь, помогите бедному студенту уже вторый день мучаюсь
Передаю массив из PHP в jQuery таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [obj] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 294413
                    [name] => Hotel1
                    [hotel_rating_id] => 7
                    [region_id] => 6742
                    [type_id] => 1,2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1301276
                    [name] => Hotel2
                    [hotel_rating_id] => 3
                    [region_id] => 9600
                    [type_id] => 1,2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1339761
                    [name] => Hotel3
                    [hotel_rating_id] => 3
                    [region_id] => 38154
                    [type_id] => 1
                )
           )
  )
```

Далее вот так его принимаю в jquery:

```
 name_hotel = new Object([]);
    id_hotel = new Object([] );

    hotel_name.obj.forEach(function (t) {
        id_hotel.push(t.id);
        name_hotel.push(t.name)

       hotel= {id: id_hotel, name: name_hotel};

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source:hotel['name'],
            select:function(event,ui){
                alert(ui.item.id);
        }});

    });
```

По примеру работы autocomplete просто передается обьект hotel а не hotel['name'] но у меня только так работает, а вот при выборе елемента не могу подтянуть  соответствующий id, подозреваю что не правильно составил обьект, но как его составить уже не знаю, как только не пробовал ничего не работает, js только начал изучать знаний маловато, если кто может помочь буду очень признателен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился, надо было вместо ключа `name` прописать в php массиве `value` и он прекрасно принимает его в таком виде какой есть.